# Easier way to do the following

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a script which slides thought some customers quotes.  See code below

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".da-feedback .da-quote").hide();
  jQuery(".da-feedback .da-quote:first-child").show();
  setTimeout('NextItem(1)',6000);
});

function NextItem($n) {

 jQuery('.da-feedback .da-quote:nth-child('+$n+')').slideUp('slow');
 $n = $n + 1;
 jQuery('.da-feedback .da-quote:nth-child('+$n+')').slideDown('slow');
 setTimeout('NextItem('+$n+')',6000);
}

</script>

<div class="da-feedback">
   <div class="da-quote" style="display: none; ">....</div>
   <div class="da-quote" style="display: none; ">....</div>
   <div class="da-quote" style="display: none; ">....</div>
</div>
```

I would like to know if jquerys gives you a function to make this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into `.delay()`?

```
function NextItem(n) {
    $('.da-feedback .da-quote:nth-child('+$n+')').slideUp('slow')
        .delay(6000).slideDown('slow', NextItem(n++)); 
    // callback fires upon completion
};
NextItem(1);
```

Incidentally, it doesn't actually affect anything, but with JavaScript you don't need to start your variables with a $, and with jQuery it's considered a convention to do so if and only if the variable is a jQuery object.

Comment: That looks a lots cleaner.  I know i didn't mention this but how would you make it loop...

Comment: It already should -- when `.slideDown` completes it fires a callback function, which in this case is a recursive call to `NextItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)() and jQuery [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)() and [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)() methods.

Ohw...and maybe [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)() might also be of service for you.